# sphinx for multiple, separate documents

Tags: python-sphinx, toctree

I'm pretty new to Sphinx, documenting my project on a server. Now a co-worker sees what I've been up to and she wants to do the same thing--document her project on the same server.

The projects are not related (they don't belong in a single TOCtree) and I don't know how to help her. Can I configure sphinx to build separate document trees? Is it as simple as making two copies of the Makefile and have it set different source/build directories?

thanks,
--Tim

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I think you want to treat them as separate projects. For that you should just copy the current build tree as you stated, and edited the `config.py` file. The other options is just to start from scratch by running `sphinx-quickstart`.

Also, keep in mind that you can reference topics between the two documents by using the [Intersphinx plugin](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/intersphinx.html).